# Enforcing xmin = ymin in a MATLAB plot

Tags: matlab, plot, axes

Without specifying any values, how can I write code that will align the plot axes such that the minimum axis value of either x or y (that MATLAB will choose automatically if unassigned) is now the minimum for both axes?
Example: If x *would have* started at 0 and y *would have* started at 5, I've now forced them both to be 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can get and set the bounds for the `Axes` object with its [`XLim` and `YLim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#budumk7_sep_shared-XLim) properties. These properties have have two values each, lower and upper bound. The first value is the lower bound. For example, for axes with handle 'ah', the lower x-axis bound is `ah.XLim(1)`.

You want both axes to start at the lower of the two lower bounds:

```
ah = gca; % Get the current axes, you can use a handle you already have
low = min(ah.XLim(1), ah.YLim(1));
ah.XLim(1) = low;
ah.YLim(1) = low;
```

As @Wolfie comments below, there are also the functions [`xlim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) and `ylim` to get and set the `XLim` and `YLim` properties. I always thought they were superfluous, since they don't really simplify accessing these properties.

Comment: Note that, `xlim(1)` is `min(xlim)` so you could just do `low = min([xlim, ylim])`. `xlim` and `ylim` should not be used as variable names, since they are the in built function names for getting and setting the axes limits (without needing to use `get` or `set`), as they would be used in my `low` definition at the start of this comment. With this in mind, your solution could be replaced by `xlim( [min([xlim, ylim]), max(xlim)] ); ylim( [min([xlim, ylim]), max(ylim)] )`. Reading this back, I realise I sound condescending, apologies, your logic is sound, variable names only real issue!

Comment: @Wolfie: Good points, though. Thanks! -- I think you are telling me not to post answers late at night... :)